# Weird SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) using enums

Tags: c++, enums, enumeration, segmentation-fault

I'm currently getting a very wierd SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault), not using any pointers that is, just enums; this is my code:

```
typedef enum 
{
    LIGHT,
    DARK,
    NONE
} Color;

class Board
{
    public:
        Color toMove();
    private:
        Color side;
};
```

and the implementation is:

```
Color Board::toMove()
{
    return side;
}
```

And I'm simply calling `toMove();` with results in the segmentation fault; here's gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004025ee in Board::toMove (this=0x0)
    at ...\board.cpp:19
19          return side;
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: The problem is not in this code, it is elsewhere.  You will need to show us your calling code (stripped down to the minimum possible).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This lovely hint from your debugger (`this=0x0`) suggests you tried to call `toMove()` without a valid `Board` object.

Comment: Ah right! - Because I couldn't seem to find a flaw in the calling code, but this is obvious! - I haven't seeded the board to the one calling toMove()!

Answer (score 7):

```
Board::toMove (this=0x0)
```

The `this = 0x0` is the clue: you're calling `toMove()` on a NULL `Board`. Don't do that :-)